# PDF Parsing with SWIFT

Tags: swift, parsing, pdf

I want to parse a PDF that has no images, only text. I'm trying to find pieces of text. For example to search the string "Name:" and be able to read the characters after ":".

I'm already able to open a PDF, get the number of pages, and to loop on them. The problem is when I want to use functions like `CGPDFDictionaryGetStream` or `CGPDFStreamCopyData`, because they use pointers. I have not found much info on the internet for swift programmers.

Maybe the easiest way would be to parse all the content to an NSString. Then I could do the rest.

Here my code:

```
// Get existing Pdf reference
let pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path))
let pageCount = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdf);
for index in 1...pageCount {
    let myPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, index)
    //Search somehow the string "Name:" to get whats written next
}
```

Comment: I update myself with more info for people who will have the same problem. 

Few information is at the moment available for swift programmers. 
On one hand I recommend to read how the pdf content is written inside the pdf files. Search for "PDF specification" on www.adobe.com.

On the other hand, we can find some information about how to parse PDF files with C# here:  <https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf_scan/dq_pdf_scan.html>

Comment: Do you know this collection: Maybe you can find something there:
http://ipdfdev.com/2013/03/13/pdf-frameworks-and-tools-for-ios-and-mac-os-x/

Comment: hi @JoseAntonio, it's been a long since you have asked this question. Any updates you could find?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PDFKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfdocument) to do this. It is part of the `Quartz` framework and is available on both iOS and MacOS. It is also pretty fast, I was able to search through a PDF with over 15000 characters in just 0.07s.

Here is an example:

```
import Quartz

let pdf = PDFDocument(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/...some path.../test.pdf"))

guard let contents = pdf?.string else {
    print("could not get string from pdf: \(String(describing: pdf))")
    exit(1)
}

let footNote = contents.components(separatedBy: "FOOT NOTE: ")[1] // get all the text after the first foot note

print(footNote.components(separatedBy: "\n")[0]) // print the first line of that text

// Output: "The operating system being written in C resulted in a more portable software."
```

You can also still access most of (if not all of) the properties you had before. Such as `pdf.pageCount` for the number of pages, and `pdf.page(at: <Int>)` to get a specific page.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty intensive task. There are libs like PDFKitten which are not maintained anymore. Here is a port of PDFKitten to swift that i did, with some modifications to the way the string searching / content indexing is done, as well as support for truetype fonts.

https://github.com/SimpleApp/PDFParser

[disclaimer : lib author]

[second disclaimer: this lib is 100% mit open sourced. The library has nothing to do with the company, it's not an ad or even a product, i'm posting this comment to help people, and then maybe grow a community around it, because it's a very common requirement and nothing free works well enough]

EDIT : the reason it's a pretty intensive task (not to mention all the character encoding issues), is that the PDF format doesn't have the notion of a "line of text" or even a "word". All it has is character printing instruction. Which means that if you want to find a "word", you'll have to recompute the frame of every blocks of character, using font information, and find the ones can be coalesced into a single word.

That's the reason why you won't find a lot of libraries doing those kind of features, and even some big project fail sometimes at providing correct copy/paste or text search features.