# How can I parse content from a PDF page with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, pdf

The documentation is not really clear to me. So far I reckon I need to set up a CGPDFOperatorTable and then create a CGPDFContentStreamCreateWithPage and CGPDFScannerCreate per PDF page.

The documentation refers to setting up Callbacks, but it's unclear to me how. How to actually obtain the content from a page?

This is my code so far.

```
    let pdfURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("titleofdocument", withExtension: "pdf")

    // Create pdf document
    let pdfDoc = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(pdfURL)

    // Nr of pages in this PF
    let numberOfPages = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdfDoc) as Int

    if numberOfPages <= 0 {
        // The number of pages is zero
        return
    }

    let myTable = CGPDFOperatorTableCreate()

    // lets go through every page
    for pageNr in 1...numberOfPages {

        let thisPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdfDoc, pageNr)
        let myContentStream = CGPDFContentStreamCreateWithPage(thisPage)
        let myScanner = CGPDFScannerCreate(myContentStream, myTable, nil)

        CGPDFScannerScan(myScanner)

        // Search for Content here?
        // ??

        CGPDFScannerRelease(myScanner)
        CGPDFContentStreamRelease(myContentStream)

    }

    // Release Table
    CGPDFOperatorTableRelease(myTable)
```

It's a similar question to: [PDF Parsing with SWIFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33136976/pdf-parsing-with-swift) but has no answers yet.

Comment: I reckon I have to write callbacks, that are called when the scanner scans. Can someone post an example of a callback? Is it a custom method that I register with CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback? An example would be great.

Comment: You aware of the fact the if check doesn't do anything? because it returns out of the if block and then continues executing. To make it only loop through the pages if there are pages, put everything after the if block inside of an else block.

Comment: I do. I really want to know more about callbacks. I'm aware of the if statement, thanks though!

Comment: Can you accept any of the answers or post your own to help any future readers like me? This is much requires here. @TomWolters

Comment: I added an answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33136976/pdf-parsing-with-swift , you may want to look at it

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of the callbacks implemented in Swift:

```
    let operatorTableRef = CGPDFOperatorTableCreate()

    CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback(operatorTableRef, "BT") { (scanner, info) in
        print("Begin text object")
    }
    CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback(operatorTableRef, "ET") { (scanner, info) in
        print("End text object")
    }
    CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback(operatorTableRef, "Tf") { (scanner, info) in
        print("Select font")
    }
    CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback(operatorTableRef, "Tj") { (scanner, info) in
        print("Show text")
    }
    CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback(operatorTableRef, "TJ") { (scanner, info) in
        print("Show text, allowing individual glyph positioning")
    }

    let numPages = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdfDocument)
    for pageNum in 1...numPages {
        let page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdfDocument, pageNum)
        let stream = CGPDFContentStreamCreateWithPage(page)
        let scanner = CGPDFScannerCreate(stream, operatorTableRef, nil)
        CGPDFScannerScan(scanner)
        CGPDFScannerRelease(scanner)
        CGPDFContentStreamRelease(stream)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Going to test this soon, your code looks great.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how to get data out of `info`?

Answer (score 1):

You've actually specified exactly how to do it, all you need to do is put it together and try until it works.

First of all, you need to setup a a table with callbacks as you state yourself in the beginning of your question (all code in Objective C, NOT Swift):

```
CGPDFOperatorTableRef operatorTable = CGPDFOperatorTableCreate();
CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback(operatorTable, "q", &op_q);
CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback(operatorTable, "Q", &op_Q);
```

This table contains a list of the PDF operators you want to get called for and associates a callback with them. Those callbacks are simply functions you define elsewhere:

```
static void op_q(CGPDFScannerRef s, void *info) {
    // Do whatever you have to do in here
    // info is whatever you passed to CGPDFScannerCreate
}

static void op_Q(CGPDFScannerRef s, void *info) {
    // Do whatever you have to do in here
    // info is whatever you passed to CGPDFScannerCreate
}
```

And then you create the scanner and get it going, while passing it the information you just defined.

```
// Passing "self" is just an example, you can pass whatever you want and it will be provided to your callback whenever it is called by the scanner.
CGPDFScannerRef contentStreamScanner = CGPDFScannerCreate(contentStream, operatorTable, self);
```

CGPDFScannerScan(contentStreamScanner);

If you want to see a complete example with sourcecode on how to find and process images, [check this website](http://ipdfdev.com/2012/07/02/find-images-on-pdf-pages-on-iphone-and-ipad/).

Comment: Thanks! Although I feel like I'm on the right  track and your answer really looks like what I need, I'm just not able to translate the Objective C method to a working Swift callback.

Comment: how to get data out of **info** ?

Answer (score 0):

To understand why a parser works this way, you need to read the PDF specification a bit better. A PDF file contains something close to printing instructions. Such as "move to this coordinate, print this character, move there, change the color, print the character number 23 from the font #23", etc.

The parser gives you callbacks for each instructions, with the possibility to retrieve the instruction parameters. That's all.

So, in order to get the content from a file, you need to rebuild its state manually. Which means, recompute the frames for all characters, and try to reverse-engineer the page layout. This is clearly not an easy task, and that's why people have created libraries to do so.

You may want to have a look at [PDFKitten](https://github.com/KurtCode/PDFKitten) , or [PDFParser](https://github.com/SimpleApp/PDFParser) which is a Swift port with some improvement that i did.